# Create interval for recording

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of schedule templates.

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Template]
(
    [ID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Interval] [nvarchar](50) NULL,-- reception interval in minutes
    [Activate] [bit] NOT NULL,-- is the template active or not
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Therefore, only one template is active at any time, and for each template there is an n-th number of schedule intervals

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Schedule]
(
    [ID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [TemplateID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [StartTime] [nvarchar](50) NULL, --start of available recording time
    [EndTime] [nvarchar](50) NULL,--end of available recording time
    [Monday] [bit] NULL,-- True or false whether the entry is available on Monday
    [Tuesday] [bit] NULL,
    [Wednesday] [bit] NULL,
    [Thursday] [bit] NULL,
    [Friday] [bit] NULL,
    [Saturday] [bit] NULL,
    [Sunday] [bit] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I also have a table in which records and occupied time are already stored:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EventRecord]
(
    [ID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [PeopleID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [TemplateID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [DateTime] [datetime] NULL,-- date and time of an already created entry
    [Interval] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [CheckOut] [bit] NULL,
    [Details] [nvarchar](max) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I need to write a stored procedure (query) that would return the available time for recording (if possible, in one query) given:

1. Reception interval
2. Already taken time by other records
3. Days of the week.

I can build the intervals of one Schedule, but how can I do this for all Schedules of one template and exclude the time for which I signed up.

```sql
DECLARE @intervalMinutes int = 10
DECLARE @myDates TABLE
                 (
                     startTime datetime,
                     endTime datetime
                 )

DECLARE @startTime DATETIME = '2016-07-10 08:00'
DECLARE @endTime DATETIME = '2016-07-10 22:00'

;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  @startTime st
    UNION   ALL
    SELECT  DATEADD (MINUTE, @intervalMinutes, st) st
    FROM    cte
    WHERE   DATEADD (MINUTE, @intervalMinutes, st) < @endTime
)
SELECT st, DATEADD (MINUTE, @intervalMinutes, st) 
FROM cte
```

Comment: sorry, apparently overlooked

Comment: Sample input and expected results would help. Why are you storing dates and numbers in `nvarchar`?

Comment: In StartTime and EndTime, I add values from the program that set the available times at which to stock up. For example: 09:00, 22:00

Comment: Yes I understand, but why are you not storing them in `date`, `time` or `datetime` columns, why `nvarchar`? And please add sample input and expected results